# Description Field not showing when post with linkedin Share API

Tags: linkedin-api

{
  "comment": "Here is my comment",
  "content": {
    "title": "Here is my title",
    "description": "Description:  The picture will be of a blue and gold macaw",
    "submitted-url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaw",
    "submitted-image-url": "http://yourshot.nationalgeographic.com/u/ss/fQYSUbVfts-T7pS2VP2wnKyN8wxywmXtY0-FwsgxoJBD4C1qJrqA8EfaP7jL8gZYg0MJlb9NNBxrHhmaSdwF/"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }
}

Comment: Having the exact same problem here. Did you find an answer to your question?